# python write method append

Tags: python, eclipse, append

I'm stuck in a very basic problem of I/O in python. I'd like to insert some line in existing file (called ofe, output file), extracted from an source file (called ife, input file) according to arguments passed by user as stored in an list called lineRange (which has an index idx and values lineNumber). 
This is the result:

```
for ifeidx,ifeline in enumerate(ife,1):   #for each line of the input file...
    with open(outFile,'r+') as ofe:
        for idx,lineNumber in enumerate(lineRange,1): #... check if it's present in desired list of lines...
            if (ifeidx == lineNumber):   #...if found...
                ofeidx = 0  
                for ofeidx, ofeline in enumerate(ofe,1):
                    if (ofeidx == idx):  #...just scroll the the output file and find which is the exact position in desired list... 
                        ofe.write(ifeline)  #...put the desired line in correct order. !!! This is always appending at the end of out file!!!!
                        break
```

Problem is, the write() method is always pointing to the end of file, appending the lines instead of inserting them when scrolling the output file.
I really don't understand what's happening since the file is open in read+write (r+) mode, neither append (a) nor read+append (r+a) mode, .
I'm also aware that code will (should) overwrite the output file lines. Additional information are the OS WIndow7, Python version 2.7 and development tool is Eclipse with PyDev 3.7.1.xx

Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can start by reading the whole file with readlines(), which will return a list. After that you just need to do list.insert(index, value) and write it again back to the file.

```
with open(outFile, "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()

data.insert(index, value)

with open(outFile, "w+") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Of course you should change this approach if you are dealing with a huge file.

By the way, if you are not using the `with` statement you should close the file in the end.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it was a different approach I also took in account but the possibility to deal with very large files made me prefer not to load the whole input file in the memory as a list. Your help is still appreciated nonetheless.